# Usage of include (graphics, section's and only)

Tags: floats, sectioning, include

I'm working on my master thesis in LaTex (using TexMaker). I'm a bit new but getting the hang of it.

At the moment i'm making my sections in different tex documents. For example, i have an abstract, my point of research, and protection. I have one directory called *MasterThesis*. In this directory i have four directory's called *Abstract*, *Point of research*, *Protection* and *Figures*. I will have one document where i will put all these sections together (with a "\include"). Now my qeustion is, is there some way to easy work at one section at a time. Without having to much problems with going back to every section and comment out the preamble and \begin & \end. Or is using includeonly the only way?

At the moment i "print out" (F1) a pdf in my sections, to see how things like formulas and such look, i don't use the inlcudeonly. So with figures i always refer to the directory above. But this gives problems when working with include (can't find the figure). So my qeustion for this part is if there is a way to have all my figures from my thesis in one folder. or is it better to make a figure folder in every section directory (wich will give problems with refering when using labels in other sections i geus? like if in section 3 i refer to a figure of section 2?)

Thanks for the help. If something is unclear, please ask. English isn't my mothertongue and i understand having a good way of working from the start is kinda crucial. So thats why i have these qeustions :D

Ps: to give a visual representation for the directory's:

-Masterthesis

- Abstract

  - (abstract.tex etc)
- Point of Research

  - (point of research.tex etc)
- Protection

  - (protection.tex etc)
- Figures

  - (lots of figures)

Comment: If i understood you correctly, the path to the figure `figurename` is `./Figures/figurename.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX IDEs  (I use AUC-TeX with xemacs) allow you to e.g. process just the file being edited, or even just a range in it. Check the documentation, or ask around for suggestions for your platform.